# Quarkus with JUnit mock only 1 method from a class while keeping the other methods real

Tags: java, unit-testing, quarkus

Hello I have a class that makes a database call with the method

`callDatabase()`

It also has another method `doOtherStuff()`

When I run my unit test I don't want the `callDatabase()` method to run But i can't figure out how to achieve this.

my Attempt so far

```java
        Service mock = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mock).callDatabase(any(), any(), any());
        QuarkusMock.installMockForType(mock, Service.class);
```

Now I would assume this mocks the callDatabase method but it seems to create a mock for the entire `Service` object so my test is failing because `doOtherStuff()` just returns null because `Service` is a mocked object

Comment: It seems that what you want is _partial mocking_. You can use `Mockito.spy()` for that, instead of `mock()`.